# How should I using C# to read partition table/boot sector?

Tags: c#

Hi i'v look through the WMI class... but none can help me in getting the partition table information... now i'm having a project which is to display the USB thumbdrive's .MBR how should i go about it? really puzzle... Any help and guide will be very much appreciated!

p.s. the code can only be written in C#

**Edit**

Thank you! I've browse through the CreateFile documentation... Still wondering how should I use P/Invoke to call CreateFile and to read the boot sector( display out the .MBR )? Do you have any reference code for this portion? Thank you once again!!

Comment: Care to explain why it has to be written in C#? This seems like an arbitrary (i.e. most-likely management-led) restriction.

Comment: Also, do you really need to look through the MBR, or do you just need to find all logical volumes backed by the USB drive?  The latter is a bit easier than the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're prepared to parse the raw information yourself, you can use P/Invoke to call CreateFile. If your user account has enough mojo, you can open the raw disk device by passing it a string, something like `"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0"`. See the documentation for CreateFile for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you want you can use WMI to get information about any drive. To do this you need to query the corresponding WMI classes. With C# you must add these references:

```
System.Management
```

and using statements:

```
using System.Management;
```

To get disk info for which are attached to your computer you can use this query:

```
Select * From Win32_DiskDrive
```

with C#, you can query like:

```
SelectQuery wmi_sorgusu = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive");
ManagementObjectSearcher wmi_bulucu = new ManagementObjectSearcher( wmi_sorgusu );

foreach (ManagementObject wmi_nesne in wmi_bulucu.Get()) {
    Console.WriteLine(wmi_nesne.GetPropertyValue( "DeviceID" ).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(wmi_nesne.GetPropertyValue( "InterfaceType" ).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(wmi_nesne.GetPropertyValue( "Caption" ).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(wmi_nesne.GetPropertyValue( "Status" ).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(wmi_nesne.GetPropertyValue( "MediaLoaded" ).ToString());
    //... etc
}
```

After getting the device parameters, you can use the same method to query Win32_DiskPartition WMI Class. You can give the device parameters to SELECT query as WHERE clause. Queries to Win32_DiskPartition returns all the partitions of all drives attached to system.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would be very much surprised if you can't open it with IO.FileStream with the same magic path.

Comment: Be very much surprised, then.  It refuses to try to open specifically those magic paths.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed C# FileStream cannot open physical device directly:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: FileStream will not
>   open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use
>   of "\.\" in the path.